# How to hide everything inside a p tag except span jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<p>` tag that I need to hide the text in. There is also a `<span>` inside the `<p>` of which I dont want to hide this text. Is this possible to do without changing the markup using jQuery?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghogdc0x/2/

html:

```
<p class="class">
    <span>Text not to hide</span>
    <br>
    Text to hide
</p>
```

Comment: Please mark the best answer as accepted in order to help future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the css visibility property:

```
$('.class').css('visibility', 'hidden');
$('.class').children().css('visibility', 'visible');
```

[Here is a working codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/epOQOb)

And then you could make it visible again by doing:

```
$('.class').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Comment: Note that this way does not remove element from the flow of the page, and just makes it invisible.

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can copy span element near the p tag, and then hide the p tag. Try this:

```
$("p").after($("p span"))
$("p").hide()
```

Comment: This is very wrong. This modifies the DOM structure. This  also duplicates the contents. http://jsfiddle.net/rjnw6d15/

Comment: This makes changes in the DOM, but not in the markup. And makes no problem if you be careful about what you do. And this is the only way that can do this, without using invisible tricks.

Comment: How is he/she supposed to be careful? What are "invisible tricks"? And no, this is not the only solution, in fact your suggested code is not even a solution as it doesn't solve the problem if there are more than one `p` element.

Comment: Careful about not to showing that element again, or to remove newly created element, etc. There are many ways that can prevent from a problem. This is a general answer and can be improved in way that it is needed to be. You can see invisible tricks in other answers, that do not really hide elements from the flow of the page. IF THERE ARE ..., yes there are many ifs that you can say, but for this question, this is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide text nodes. You can only remove them or wrap them with another element and hide that wrapper element.

The following code snippet hides non-span elements and removes text-nodes children.

```
$('p.class').contents().each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) ) {
        $this.remove();
        // in case that you just want to hide the text node
        // $this.wrap('<i>').parent().hide();
   } else if ( this.nodeType === 1 && this.tagName !== 'SPAN' ) {
       $this.hide();
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xxpopvje/

Answer (score 0):

Use this and try to wrap the text to be hide in a wrapper p element like

```
<p><span>Text not to hide</span><br/><p>Text to hide</p></p>

$('p').find('*').not('span').css('display','none');
```